# Stack Editors and Views

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm using E4, where all views and editors are parts and can be stacked on top of each other. However, I'm using the compatibility layer (aka the lesser evil). Still, stacking is possible, I can manually put views on top of editors and vice versa.

The question is now: How to configure the perspective, so that editors and views are stacked *on default*?

I tried to implement the `IPerspectiveFactory`:

```
    final IFolderLayout mainFolder = layout.createFolder("main", IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.95f, layout.getEditorArea()); //$NON-NLS-1$
    mainFolder.addPlaceholder("*"); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

But there is no constant `IPageLayout.STACK`, and the above snippet does not work either.

I tried to configure the extension point, but could not figure out how to add placeholders. Also, it seems it does not work with the intro view.

So how do I stack views and editors programmatically?